# In the Dir function (VBA) what is the function of the "ReadOnly" attribute? Seems vbNormal lists "ReadOnly" files too

Tags: vba

I was wondering what "ReadOnly" does. VbNormal returns all "ReadOnly" files too, so "vbNormal + vbReadOnly" combination seems to have no effect. But I guess it has to have some function.

Thank you very much for your idea.

```
Sub test()

x = Dir("C:\Folder\", vbNormal)   'It returns read-only files as well, but vbReadOnly is not given as condition

Do While x <> ""

        Debug.Print x
        x = Dir
        
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: From docs: *Specifies read-only files in addition to files with no attributes.*. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dir-function

Comment: How are you determining that the file is ReadOnly?  Be specific.

Comment: Looks like `Dir()` starts with all files with no attributes and then add files to that list, without a clear way of *only* getting files-with-attributes. That appears to be its only use, adding more files to the basic set. I guess you have to filter after the fact.

Comment: I right click a file, and click "ReadOnly". Then I launch again the sub procedure. But it gets listed if the condition is "vbNormal" too. So seems like vbNormal lists files with "ReadOnly" attributes already. But then I don't understand what is the use of "vbReadOnly" attribute, seems to have no use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dir (and Dir$) functions are pretty ancient (they actually precede *Microsoft*) and I suspect that parts of them became obsolete long ago, but that the Help/Doc pages are autogenerated (VBA isn't really under active maintenance) so they keep spitting out irrelevant/misleading information.

O'Reilly seems to agree with this ([here](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/vb-vba/1565923588/1565923588_ch07-592-fm2xml.html)) saying the vbReadOnly flag (and some others) is a no-op.  My suspicion is that the obsolete flags worked back in DOS days, but became disabled when everything was transferred to NT.

Comment: Thank you, great to see some confirming opinions, my practical test had the same result. Thank you very much!!

Comment: If fact, the O'Reilly page was the only source I could find for the information - and according to the meta data of the page, it is from 1998. Btw: You can use the `GetAttr`-function to check if a file has the ReadOnly-attribute set - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/getattr-function