# Why does the Dir function in ms access VBA pick up read-only files with default attributes set?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to get names of all files in a folder but I'd like to ignore the ones that are **read-only.** I can't figure out why the following simple code doesn't work:

```
x = Dir("C:\Users\" & "*.*", vbNormal)
Do While x <> ""
     Debug.Print x
     x = Dir
Loop
```

The directory contains a single test.xlsx file that is set to read-only, but the program still prints out the name. As far as I understand the documentation https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/dir-function-1a1a4275-f92f-4ae4-8b87-41e4513bba2e , it should be omitted since I did not include vbReadOnly as an attribute, in fact only files with no attributes at all should be picked up.

I'm probably missing something obvious, but I just can't figure out what it is?

Comment: Previously: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66693087/in-the-dir-function-vba-what-is-the-function-of-the-readonly-attribute-seem

Comment: @TimWilliams Missed that one, thanks!